# bigquery overcharges when selecting just few rows

Tags: google-bigquery

select DATE(request_time) from logs.nobids_05 limit 1 
gave me  "3.48 GB processed" which a bit much considering that request_time is a field that appears in each row.

There are many other cases where just touching column automatically adds its total size to the cost. For example,

```
select * from logs.nobids_05 limit 1
```

gives me "This query will process 274 GB when run". 
I am sure bigquery does not need to read 274GB for outputting 1 row of data.

Comment: This question is about technological issue and talks about possible bug in the charging algorithm of Google bigquery. I am notifying bigquery team about this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**2019 update**: IF you cluster your tables, the cost of a `SELECT * LIMIT 1` will be minimal.

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

---

Running a "SELECT * FROM big_table LIMIT 1" with BigQuery would be the equivalent of doing this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZ-slvv_ZT4.

BigQuery is an analytical database. It's architecture and pricing are optimized for analysis at scale, not for single row handling.

Every operation in BigQuery involves a full table scan, but only of the columns mentioned in the query. The goal is to have predictable costs: Before running the query you are able to know how much data will be involved, therefore its cost. It might seem a big price to query just one row, but the good news is the cost remains constant, even when the queries get way more complex and CPU intensive.

Once in a while you might need to run a single row query, and the costs might seem excessive, but the assumption here is that you are using this tool to analyze data at scale, and the overall costs of having data stored in it should be more than competitive with other tools available. Since you've been working with other tools, I'd love to see a total cost comparison of analytical sessions within real case scenarios.

By the way, BigQuery has a better way for doing the equivalent of "SELECT * LIMIT x". It's free, and it relies on the REST API instead of querying:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list

This being said, thanks for the feedback, as there is a balancing job between making pricing more complex and the tool better suited for other jobs - and this balance is built on the feedback we get.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Unfortunately in real case scenarios an operator wants to see some of the data *before* he writes more complex guery. The process is iterative: I write a simple "select .. from .. where .. limit k" query, check the results, write more complex query based on what i see etc... 
Consider, for example, using bigquery specific functions related to hierarchical structure - I will never remember all of them, I would need to try them before.... Anyway, I understand from you that it's working as intended so I am closing this question.

Comment: Yes! It totally makes sense to work on a smaller dataset when trying queries out. The best way to do that on BigQuery is to extract a small sample from the big dataset into a new table, and work on it - then just change the name of the queried table when running on the real thing. As a real world example, that's exactly what Shine Tech does when working with multiple terabyte long tables: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSLU8Gxt-rc.

Comment: I use table decorators to query small samples of the dataset and be charged only for them .  Although it covers only fresh data...

Comment: I like the "free" part: is that documented anywhere, that it's free? Is that what "List" under "Metadata operations" means in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing? (Since this is getting real rows, I think of this as "real" data, not metadata, but w/e.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a bug. "When you run a query, you're charged according to the total data processed in the columns you select, even if you set an explicit LIMIT on the results." (https://developers.google.com/bigquery/pricing#samplecosts)